# web-pack configuration is not valid: configuration has an unknown property 'devserver'. These properties are valid

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i feel there is some problem with node.js windows fire wall blocking some features of node.js :server side javascript on all public and privet networks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo, the actual property name must be `devServer`

Comment: Just explain pls

Comment: webpack tells you that the property `devserver` does not exists it has case sensitive devserver and devServer are not the same word

Comment: It doesn't open in web browser